# math.round vs parseInt

Tags: javascript

Have a quick JS question. What is the difference between math.round and parseInt?

I made a JS script to sum the inverses of prompted numbers:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var numRep = prompt("How many repetitions would you like to run?");
    var sum = 0; 
    var count = 0;
    var i = 1;     //variable i becomes 1


    while (i <= numRep)  {//  repeat 5 times

       var number = prompt("Please enter a non zero integer");

       if(number==0){
         document.write("Invalid Input <br>");
 count++;
       }
       else{
          document.write("The inverse is: " + 1/number + "<br>");
          sum = sum + (1/parseInt(number));  //add number to the sum
       }

       i++; //increase i by 1
    }

    if (sum==0){
    document.write("You did not enter valid input");}
    else { document.write("The sum of the inverses is: " + sum);  //display sum
    }
    </script></body></html>
```

and it uses parseInt. If I wanted to makeit use math.round, is there anything else I need to do so that It knows to limit the number of decimal places accordingly?

In other words, does math.round have to be formatted in a certain way?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. `parseInt` converts a string to an integer, whereas `Math.round()` - well - rounds a floating point number.

Comment: but the thing with parseInt is that it seems to always round numbers, like fractors for instance, to a reasonable number of characters, whereas math.round seems to round only to whole numbers

Comment: Side note: When it comes to rounding, parseInt is significantly slower than Math.round: http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/55

Comment: `Math.floor(float)` [is faster](https://jsperf.com/test-parseint-and-math-floor) and numerically do the same tham `parseInt(float)`. **The question is error-prone**, the equivalence is with *floor*, not with *round*.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, parseInt and floor return different results for negative numbers.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The two functions are really quite different.

`parseInt()` extracts a number from a string, e.g.

```
parseInt('1.5')
// => 1
```

`Math.round()` rounds the number to the nearest whole number:

```
Math.round('1.5')
// => 2
```

`parseInt()` can get its number by removing extra text, e.g.:

```
parseInt('12foo')
// => 12
```

However, Math.round will not:

```
Math.round('12foo')
// => NaN
```

You should probably use `parseFloat` and `Math.round` since you're getting input from the user:

```
var number = parseFloat(prompt('Enter number:'));
var rounded = Math.round(number);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get Math.round to round to, say 3 decimal places?

Comment: The only way I know to do that is to cheat: `Math.round(1.23456 * 1000) / 1000`

Comment: don't forget to provide number base in parseInt

Comment: If we want to round the input, we need to use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`. What good is rounding something that is already converted to int?

Comment: Updated to use `parseFloat` in the last example.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.round` will round the number to the nearest integer. `parseInt` will assure you that the value is a number

So what you will need is something like this:

```
number = parseInt(number);

if ( isNan(number) || number == 0 ){
    document.write("Invalid Input <br>");
    count++;
}
```

This will assure you that the use has put in a number

Comment: Note that this actually will allow the user to enter something like "1Password" and the result will be `1`, whereas with `Math.round` that input would actually be turned into `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

`Math.round` expects a number, `parseInt` expects a string.

Use `parseInt('12345', 10)` for parsing 10-based numbers.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm